# Android: activity with JSON don't correctly update itself

Tags: android, json

in my activity I have a textfield, which has to fill with some data received from a JSON call. If I open the activity for the first time, the field is empty; but, if I go out from the activity and then I reopen it (or, if I put in standby my phone and I reactivate it), JSON works correctly and the field is filled with correct data. Very strange! How can I fix it? I copy below the activity. Thanks!

```html
package com.mycom.myapp.Views;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.mycom.myapp.R;
import com.mycom.myapp.Utility.ClsJSONProcess;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView ConditionField;
    String urlString = "";
 String AlertText="";    
 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity);    
    ConditionField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myActivityGuardMessage);          
    urlString="https://myurl.com/point?latitude=46.501616&longitude=11.340313&radius=0.5";
    

    //This is the JSON code!
    ClsJSONProcess ActiveProcess = new ClsJSONProcess();
    ActiveProcess.execute(urlString);
    int JSONArrayLength = ActiveProcess.getJSONArrayLength();
    String JSONArray[][] = new String[ActiveProcess.getJSONArrayLength()][9];
    if (ActiveProcess.getJSONArray() != null) {

    AlertText = AlertText + ActiveProcess.getJSONArray()[0][1]
    }
    ConditionField.setText(AlertText);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the ClsJSONProcess is an AsyncTask?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No, isn't an async task... Can you write an example?

Comment: Can you first write ClsJSONProcess class. To know what is going on inside

Comment: It looks like you are running network connection on your main thread , execute network connection on a seperate thread and communicate with thUI thread via a handler